# ReactJS auth redirect before application loads

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am designing a React application consisting of multiple components.

In my organisation they use a kind of Authentication mechanism wherein one needs to check a particular cookie; if available user is considered authenticated and is allowed to view app. If cookie is not there / expired then one needs to direct the user to a particular URL wherein he can fill in his user id and password and then that URL redirects him to original application along with valid cookie.

I am thinking how this can be achieved in my React application... I know there is componentWillMount method but shouldn’t user first get authenticated before any of the component loads?

How to implement this?

Guidance appreciated

Cheers

Comment: How about just put the function in your entry point of js (e.g. index.js)? But it will block your full application running & rendering

Comment: see Redux, it's store may help you control the login state of a user

Answer (score 6):

If you are using react-router you have to create protected route component, which checks if user is authenticated.

Then your routes file should look like this:

```
import { Route, Redirect, BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

    const ProtectedRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
      <Route {...rest} render={props => (
        auth.isAuthenticated ? (
          <Component {...props}/>
        ) : (
          <Redirect to={{
            pathname: '/login',
            state: { from: props.location }
          }}/>
        )
      )}/>
    )

export const Routes = () => (

    <BrowserRouter>
      <Route path='/' component={Index}/>
      <ProtectedRoute path='/access' component={Access}/>
    </BrowserRouter>

)
```

For more details check the official [**example**](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow) on auth redirects.

Answer (score 4):

You have several cases of handling authentication redirection / token expiration.

**1. At start time**

1. Wait for the `redux-persist` to finish loading and injecting in the `Provider` component
2. Set the Login component as the parent of all the other components
3. Check if the token is still valid
   3.1. Yes: Display the children
   3.2. No: Display the login form

**2. When the user is currently using the application**

You should use the power of middlewares and check the token validity in every `dispatch` the user makes.

If the token is expired, dispatch an action to invalidate the token. Otherwise, continue as if nothing happened.

Take a look at the middleware `token.js` below.

---

I wrote a whole sample of code for your to use and adapt it if needed.

The solution I propose below is router agnostic.
You can use it if you use `react-router` but also with any other router.

**App entry point: app.js**

See that the `Login` component is on top of the routers

```
import React from 'react';

import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import { syncHistoryWithStore } from 'react-router-redux';

import createRoutes from './routes'; // Contains the routes
import { initStore, persistReduxStore } from './store';
import { appExample } from './container/reducers';

import Login from './views/login';

const store = initStore(appExample);

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { rehydrated: false };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    persistReduxStore(store)(() => this.setState({ rehydrated: true }));
  }

  render() {
    const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, store);
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Login>
          {createRoutes(history)}
        </Login>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

**store.js**

The key to remember here is to use `redux-persist` and keep the login reducer in the local storage (or whatever storage).

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { persistStore, autoRehydrate } from 'redux-persist';
import localForage from 'localforage';
import { routerReducer } from 'react-router-redux';

import reducers from './container/reducers';
import middlewares from './middlewares';

const reducer = combineReducers({
  ...reducers,
  routing: routerReducer,
});

export const initStore = (state) => {
  const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
  const store = createStore(
    reducer,
    {},
    composeEnhancers(
      applyMiddleware(...middlewares),
      autoRehydrate(),
    ),
  );

  persistStore(store, {
    storage: localForage,
    whitelist: ['login'],
  });

  return store;
};

export const persistReduxStore = store => (callback) => {
  return persistStore(store, {
    storage: localForage,
    whitelist: ['login'],
  }, callback);
};
```

**Middleware: token.js**

This is a middleware to add in order to check wether the token is still valid.

If the token is no longer valid, a dispatch is trigger to invalidate it.

```
import jwtDecode from 'jwt-decode';
import isAfter from 'date-fns/is_after';

import * as actions from '../container/actions';

export default function checkToken({ dispatch, getState }) {
  return next => (action) => {
    const login = getState().login;

    if (!login.isInvalidated) {
      const exp = new Date(jwtDecode(login.token).exp * 1000);
      if (isAfter(new Date(), exp)) {
        setTimeout(() => dispatch(actions.invalidateToken()), 0);
      }
    }

    return next(action);
  };
}
```

**Login Component**

The most important thing here is the test of **`if (!login.isInvalidated)`**.

If the login data is not invalidated, it means that the user is connected and the token is still valid. (Otherwise it would have been invalidated with the middleware `token.js`)

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import * as actions from '../../container/actions';

const Login = (props) => {
  const {
    dispatch,
    login,
    children,
  } = props;

  if (!login.isInvalidated) {
    return <div>children</div>;
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={(event) => {
      dispatch(actions.submitLogin(login.values));
      event.preventDefault();
    }}>
      <input
        value={login.values.email}
        onChange={event => dispatch({ type: 'setLoginValues', values: { email: event.target.value } })}
      />
      <input
        value={login.values.password}
        onChange={event => dispatch({ type: 'setLoginValues', values: { password: event.target.value } })}
      />
      <button>Login</button>
    </form>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = (reducers) => {
  return {
    login: reducers.login,
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Login);
```

**Login actions**

```
export function submitLogin(values) {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch({ type: 'readLogin' });
    return fetch({}) // !!! Call your API with the login & password !!!
      .then((result) => {
        dispatch(setToken(result));
        setUserToken(result.token);
      })
      .catch(error => dispatch(addLoginError(error)));
  };
}

export function setToken(result) {
  return {
    type: 'setToken',
    ...result,
  };
}

export function addLoginError(error) {
  return {
    type: 'addLoginError',
    error,
  };
}

export function setLoginValues(values) {
  return {
    type: 'setLoginValues',
    values,
  };
}

export function setLoginErrors(errors) {
  return {
    type: 'setLoginErrors',
    errors,
  };
}

export function invalidateToken() {
  return {
    type: 'invalidateToken',
  };
}
```

**Login reducers**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import assign from 'lodash/assign';
import jwtDecode from 'jwt-decode';

export default combineReducers({
  isInvalidated,
  isFetching,
  token,
  tokenExpires,
  userId,
  values,
  errors,
});

function isInvalidated(state = true, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'readLogin':
    case 'invalidateToken':
      return true;
    case 'setToken':
      return false;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

function isFetching(state = false, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'readLogin':
      return true;
    case 'setToken':
      return false;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export function values(state = {}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'resetLoginValues':
    case 'invalidateToken':
      return {};
    case 'setLoginValues':
      return assign({}, state, action.values);
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export function token(state = null, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'invalidateToken':
      return null;
    case 'setToken':
      return action.token;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export function userId(state = null, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'invalidateToken':
      return null;
    case 'setToken': {
      const { user_id } = jwtDecode(action.token);
      return user_id;
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export function tokenExpires(state = null, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'invalidateToken':
      return null;
    case 'setToken':
      return action.expire;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export function errors(state = [], action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'addLoginError':
      return [
        ...state,
        action.error,
      ];
    case 'setToken':
      return state.length > 0 ? [] : state;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Hope it helps.